# Inserting data into multiple tables PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, dataset

I have a basic data structure for storing recipes. It consists of three tables as below:

**Table 1 - Recipes (recipe_id, recipe_name)**

**Table 2 - Ingredients (ingredient_id, ingredient_name)**

**Table 3 - Recipe_Ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id)**

I have come across a problem when adding a new recipe and would like to know the best practice for inserting.

Currently, on submitting the form I insert into the **Recipes** table, the recipe_id is auto generated. I then insert into the **Ingredients** table, again the ingredient_id is auto generated. The third step on submit is to then insert into the **Recipe_Ingredients** table, but how do I get the values of the recipe and ingredient ids that have just been created in order to insert them into the **Recipe_Ingredients** table?

I currently have separate PHP functions to insert into the **Recipes** and **Ingredients** tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the inserted id value after each insert operation.

The function to get the last insert id is: [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Cheers cnkt. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_insert_id()` will give you the auto generated id of the rows you just inserted

Comment: This is a duplicate answer, why add it?

Comment: Look at the times of the both posts.

Answer (score 0):

After each insert, do `mysql_insert_id()` I think, so it gets back the inserted id of the previous insert.