# Writing INSERT query for multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

I am writing a recipe database app and I have the database schema sorted but I am not struggling to figure out what query to write to insert the recipe into the database.

I have 3 tables

**ingredients**
ingredients_id...

**recipes**
recipe_id ...

**recipes (pivot table)**
ingredients_id
recipe_id

but it was my understanding that you can only insert data into one table at a time.

This is where my problem lies. If I have a form to input a recipe how do I add the recipe which is split over 3 tables? Do i use multiple queries. If so how can I guarantee they will match.

Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question but it is frying my brain, thanks in advance for the feedback.

Best regards

Comment: either use several inserts or use one insert with triggers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961967/inserting-data-into-multiple-tables-php-mysql?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert into multiple tables? (Database normalization?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guarantee the rows are related to one another by assigning common values to the appropriate columns.

If you have decided to define the `recipe_id` column in `recipes` to be AUTO_INCREMENT, and you insert a row which has a generated value assigned to that column, you can use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to retrieve the value assigned to the column

```
INSERT INTO recipes (recipe_id, col2, col3) VALUES (NULL, 'fee', 'fi');
```

If the insert statement succeeded, you can retrieve the value assigned to recipe_id column (in the same MySQL session, before you execute any other statements), by executing a statement like this:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS recipe_id;
```

NOTE: Some MySQL client libraries have methods/functions that perform this for you, so you can retrieve the value without having to prepare and execute another SQL statement in your code, e.g.

**`PDO::lastInsertId`** ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

**`mysqli::$insert_id`** ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

You could then supply the value returned in the INSERT to the association table, for example

```
INSERT INTO recipe_ingredient (recipe_id, ... ) VALUES ( 42, ... )
```

Comment: Thanks this is just what I have been looking for.